# Incorrect initial question count on Stack Overflow front page

Tags: bug, statistics, homepage

I noticed earlier this morning that when I navigate to http://stackoverflow.com, I see an incorrect question count:

[image: Wrong question count]

When I switch to another tab and back to the "New" tab, I see a different question count:

[image: Different question count]

Even two hours later, the initial question count is always 96. (Is this a default in the page template that doesn't get updated correctly?)

Will this be fixed anytime soon? It doesn't matter so much which of these two numbers is the correct one, the important thing here is that the number should not depend on *how* I got on the "New" tab.

**Update:** It appears to be that the reason for the changing number is that the filter on the "New" tab gets silently changed from "Recommended" to "All tags" (as mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300818/240733)). So perhaps *that* should be fixed, I'd expect this filter to stay on the same setting until I decide to change it.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261337/why-does-the-question-filter-always-return-96-questions ?

Comment: In chrome, to get the most accurate count, open the questions page in an incognito window and then check the number. That is the accurate one.

Comment: This is like the 10th question I've seen on why is the question count 96... Perhaps someone can make a feature post explaining that its not a bug.

Comment: @AshleyMedway: **1.** I am not just asking why. I am suggesting that the question count is changed. **2.** Perhaps there is a reason that this gets asked so often... perhaps simply because this UI behaviour is unintuitive to many users. (No, I do not have statistics on that claim. It's just a suggestion.)

Comment: @AshleyMedway So the number of posts does not even change but always returns 96 when a filter is applied that the user has not set because 96 is the number of posts that at some point was displayed by default on the homepage ? You know, as a "feature" description this sounds rather daft (personally I'm not bothered but I can understand why somebody would want that changed).

Comment: Related MSE post to change 96 to 100: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261968/245360.

Answer (score 4):

My two cents:

It's the count of questions that are always shown on the "Newest" tab with the tag filter set to "Recommended". I only ever see two pages (with the per-page left at the default of 50), and the second page is always shorter. So, without actually doing a count, I assume it's 50+46 questions, for the total count of 96 that's always visible.

You'll notice on your second screen-capture that the tag filter is set to "All tags", which is why the count jumps by ~9 million.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have made it clear enough in my original question that, while I *was* wondering where that number came from, I simply wanted to suggest with my post that this illogical behaviour of the SO UI be fixed.

Comment: @stakx So what behavior do you want to see? That when you switch back to the New tab it has the same filter as what you had when you were last there?

Comment: Obviously the correct behaviour would be that the question count is not dependent on *how* I got on the "New" tab. I don't care whether the question count depends on a personal filter or not. (However, if the personal filter is not active initially and then suddenly decides to kick in, perhaps *that* should be fixed. I'd expect the filter to either be always on, or always off, depending on my preferences which I set explicitly; I don't expect features to enable/disable themselves at random moments.)