# Is it just me, or is the SO question counter stuck?

Tags: bug, new-nav, homepage

I think the question counter on SO got reset after the 1,000,000 questions mark.  However, it seems to be glitching out for me now and looks like it is stuck at 96.
[image]

It has been stuck there for 3 days, unsure whats happening.

*Yes I have done a hard reload*

**NOT A DUPLICATE**

This question is **NOT** a duplicate of [Why does the "new" > "recommended" tab give always 96 questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299057/why-does-the-new-recommended-tab-give-always-96-questions) or [Why does the "new" > "recommended" tab give always 96 questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299057/why-does-the-new-recommended-tab-give-always-96-questions).  These questions refer to the amount when being filtered or in the recommended tab.  My issue always happens.

**EDIT:** Removing the new navbar seems to fix it, so it is an issue with the old nav.

Comment: Counter looks fine for me. Might be limited to the new nav view.

Comment: @Mat Interesting observation, I did not think of that.  I am going to try the old nav view, maybe it will work better.

Comment: @rene At first glance this does look like a duplicate, but it seems to be only under a certain condition when that happens in that quest, like when on the recommended page.  Also that was older and still unresolved.

Comment: Let's blame caching instead ...

Comment: @rene must be on their end then, I did a hard reload.

Comment: Yes @HurricaneDevelopment pages that are hit often are cached heavily server side, [some up to hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how/69172#69172). Other duplicate here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300747/incorrect-initial-question-count-on-stack-overflow-front-page/300818#300818

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment: but that's the thing, you are using the recommended tags view.

Comment: Your *EDIT* section makes no sense. If removing the new navbar feature fixes it, it is not an issue with the old nav.

Comment: During an upgrade, it got bound to the 'GOOD_QUESTIONS' table by mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You have the view set to *recommended*. On the homepage, with the *new* tab selected and set to *recommended*, you always get a fixed 96 questions:

> [image: home page with recommended selected]

The direct URL for this view is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive. The number 96 was picked for [historical reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261337/why-does-the-question-filter-always-return-96-questions).

Set that selector to *all tags* to get the full count again (but take into account that that view is still filtered; spam with at least 3 spam flags and heavily downvoted questions are not shown, for example).

A direct URL for the *all tags* view is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tagFilter=all:

> [image: home page with all tags selected]

Comment: *You have the view set...* you assume that, right? Or can you see what I'm looking at right now .... ;)

Comment: @rene: I totally am not looking at your screen through the Stack Overflow trojan on your computer only moderators are supposed to know about.